# Cannot reassign shortcut SUPER+M under GNOME

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.5-1-ARCH
- GNOME: 3.20.0

I am unable to make use of the shortcut <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. What I've tried so far:

- assigning the shortcut to the system's email program
- assigning the shortcut to start a process `thunderbird`

However, pressing it only opens the notification bar/calendar instead.

Is this a bug or did I overlook something?

Comment: I took the alternate route of just using Ctrl+SUPER+M, seemed just as easy as trying to override the system shortcuts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work as that's one of the default `gnome-shell` shortcuts. So `gnome-shell` [actually grabs it](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2015-February/msg08980.html) even if you set it to execute some custom action. You'll have to remove it first from the default shortcuts list - easiest way is via terminal with `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray "['<Super>v']"
```

alternatively, if you prefer doing it via gui, fire up `dconf-editor`:
in the left pane, navigate to `org`>`gnome`>`shell`>`keybindings` then in the right pane right click on `toggle-message-tray` and select `customize`:

[image]

a new window will pop up: toggle `Use default value` to *OFF*:

[image]

then edit the custom value, removing `, '<Super>m'` so that it reads: `['<Super>v']` then hit *Apply*.

---

Restart your shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or log out & log in). You should then be able to use your custom <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut.